# Can anybody correct sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need city and the number of vacancies, jobs in this city. City, Resumes, Vacancy - table.

Here is a query I wrote, but it does not work (the second left join does not work)

```
SELECT c.name city_name,
COUNT(v.id) vac_num, (r.id) res_num
FROM mnk_city c
LEFT JOIN mnk_vacancy
ON v.cityId = c.id
LEFT JOIN mnk_resume
ON c.id = r.cityId
GROUP BY c.name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT c.name city_name,   
COUNT(v.id) vac_num, (r.id) res_num 
FROM mnk_city c 
LEFT JOIN mnk_vacancy v
ON v.cityId = c.id 
LEFT JOIN mnk_resume r 
ON c.id = r.cityId 
GROUP BY c.name
```

You are missing the table aliases.

Comment: You were faster in posting but I didn't see it yet - so upvote for you ;)

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are missing some table aliases - mnk_vacancy should be followed by v as far as I can see and mnk_resume should be followed by r.

```
SELECT c.name city_name,
COUNT(v.id) vac_num, (r.id) res_num
FROM mnk_city c
LEFT JOIN mnk_vacancy v
ON v.cityId = c.id
LEFT JOIN mnk_resume r
ON c.id = r.cityId
GROUP BY c.name
```